# Is clang supposed to be the same as gcc and vice versa?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang

I was trying to edit some C code, compile it, and test it. Along the way, I unintentionally used different compilers, namely gcc and clang. Then I got bored and just typed both of the compiler's commands in the command line (weird but ok). I noticed that when I did that, gcc was clang and clang was just clang. Obviously when you enter a compiler's command without arguments, you get an error saying that there are no input files. I thought gcc was supposed to say something like this when I just typed the command:

```
gcc: error: no input files
```

But it's the same when I tried it for clang. It said `clang: error: no input files` for both commands. So my question is, am I running clang when using gcc? If so, how do I fix that?

Comment: Are you using a mac

Comment: @M.M I am using a mac yes

Answer (score 1):

gcc and clang are two rather different compilers.  But due to gcc's popularity, clang deliberately copies many of its features.  And in some environments (such as recent Macs), clang is installed with an alias so that if you type `gcc`, you get `clang`.  Sounds like that's what might be happening for you.

Comment: Is there a way to remove this alias?

Comment: @MatthewSchell First confirm that `gcc` is a symlink: `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc`.  It should show as `gcc -> clang` or maybe `gcc -> cc`.  (I can't tell for sure, because I removed it on my Mac already.)  Then, if it is, and you're sure you want to, `sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc`.  (But if that breaks something, or you have second thoughts, and you want to recreate it: `cd /usr/bin; sudo ln -s clang gcc`.)

Comment: I just see `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18288 Sep 20  2019 /usr/bin/gcc` I don't think it's a symlink

Comment: No, you're right, my mistake.  Removing it would *probably* be safe, but it's hard to be sure.  It'll be safer to do something like `sudo mv gcc gcc.clang`.

Comment: Even after using sudo and going into root, I don't have the permission to rename gcc for some reason. I'm in /usr/bin

Comment: Crud.  You're right.  Apple has protected `/bin` in some special way.  In that case, if you have your own custom search path, you can put a shell script called `gcc` in an earlier directory, that just does `echo "gcc: not found" >&2` and then `exit 1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228237/discussion-between-matthew-schell-and-steve-summit).

Answer (score 0):

Apple used to use `gcc` in Xcode a long time ago, and then they made `clang` and running gcc would invoke clang to allow old build script to work correctly. If you need to use gcc you can install with homebrew like

```
brew install gcc
```

Comment: In order to actually use `gcc` instead of `clang`, without modification, the correct format would be `gcc-10 file.c` or `gcc-x`, x is the version you installed with homebrew.